# Enforce maximum length for a ReadonlyArray in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to enforce the length for `ReadonlyArray`.

I know it is possible to enforce length for a simple array in ts using `Tuple` but not sure how to achieve a similar result with `ReadonlyArray`.

```
   type Props = Readonly<{
      items: ReadonlyArray<Item>
    }>
```